# showMessage function for toast not appearing in XLPagerTabStrip

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, macos

I am using `XLPagerTabStrip` and I have two child view inside it. In the child view I am using showMessage function to print the toast for the error messages but the toast is not shown in the view.

```
if ( debit_amount > availBal_Amount )
{
    self.showMessage("NO_SUFFICIENT_BAL", type: .error, options: [.position(.bottom),.textNumberOfLines(0)])
}
```

This the showMessage function:

```
open func showMessage(_ text: String,
                      type: GSMessageType,
                      options: [GSMessageOption]? = nil) {
    GSMessage.showMessageAddedTo(text: text, type: type, options: options, inView: view, inViewController: self)    }
```

only in `XLPagerTabStrip` view `showMessage()` is not working.

Please help me in solving the issue.

Comment: Can you please share code of showMessage()?

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman I have updated the question please find the function.

Comment: ohh. you are using pod for this

Comment: yeah @TaimoorSuleman

Comment: Check the view hierarchy. Whether view is showing behind the XLPager's View or not

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code and message will show on container view.
For that created one object in viewController.

```
let child_3 = ChildExampleViewController(itemInfo: IndicatorInfo(title: " ACCOUNT", image: UIImage(named: "profile")))

child_3.showMessage("nemessage", type: .error)
```

[image: Its work for me.]

Comment: How to call it from the child page?

Comment: Using the view controller's object you can call it.

Comment: can you please tell me with an example?  Since I am an beginner.

Comment: Suppose you are adding two controllers in your container view.
So using that two controller's object you can called **showMessage** method because that method is added in UIViewController's extension.